# How to lock the x axis in x3dom

Tags: html, navigation, locking, axis, x3dom

I need to block an axis of the walk navigation to avoid pitching. The camera must go forward, left and right, but it must not look down or up.
It's possible?

Comment: Could you show us the code ?

Comment: this is the actualcode         <viewpoint DEF='Cinepresa01' description='Cinepresa01' orientation='-1.93e-05 1 -1.784e-05 -1.493' position='-900.3 -72.66 -282.6' fieldOfView='0.6024'></viewpoint>
        <navigationInfo DEF='NavInfo01' headlight='false' type='"WALK"'></navigationInfo> but in this case the camera goes in every directions

Comment: Since I haven't tried it myself, but there is the so called Turntable-Mode, c.f. https://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/example/x3dom_turntable.html with that you might achieve what want to do. If so consider answering your own question.

On a side note: Include your code in your question and format it properly.